# why does my ajax form post reload the page when submitting but then send it on the second try?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

How on earth does this happen? I have tried everything I could but finally decided to get help.

When submitting the form on live server at the first time, the page realoads and form clears and no data is sent.

After the reload, if I send the form exactly the same way again it works????

Every bit of help would be appreciated!

Associated JS

```
  /*----------- 09. Ajax Contact Form ----------*/
  var form = '.ajax-contact';
  var invalidCls = 'is-invalid';
  var $email = '[name="email"]';
  var $validation =
    '[name="name"],[name="phone"],[name="date"],[name="email"],[name="message"]'; // Must be use (,) without any space
  var formMessages = $('.form-messages');

  function sendContact() {
    var formData = $(form).serialize();
    var valid;
    valid = validateContact();
    if (true) {
      jQuery
        .ajax({
          url: $(form).attr('action'),
          data: formData,
          type: 'POST',
        })
        .done(function (response) {
          // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
          formMessages.removeClass('error');
          formMessages.addClass('success');
          // Set the message text.
          formMessages.text(response);
          // Clear the form.
          $(form + ' input:not([type="submit"]),' + form + ' textarea').val('');
        })
        .fail(function (data) {
          // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
          formMessages.removeClass('success');
          formMessages.addClass('error');
          // Set the message text.
          if (data.responseText !== '') {
            formMessages.html(data.responseText);
          } else {
            formMessages.html(
              'Hupsis! Virhe tapahtui eikä viestiä voitu lähettää, yritä uudelleen.'
            );
          }
        });
    }
  }

  function validateContact() {
    var valid = true;
    var formInput;

    function unvalid($validation) {
      $validation = $validation.split(',');
      for (var i = 0; i < $validation.length; i++) {
        formInput = form + ' ' + $validation[i];
        if (!$(formInput).val()) {
          $(formInput).addClass(invalidCls);
          valid = false;
        } else {
          $(formInput).removeClass(invalidCls);
          valid = true;
        }
      }
    }
    unvalid($validation);

    if (
      !$($email).val() ||
      !$($email)
        .val()
        .match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/)
    ) {
      $($email).addClass(invalidCls);
      valid = false;
    } else {
      $($email).removeClass(invalidCls);
      valid = true;
    }
    return valid;
  }

  $(form).on('submit', function (element) {
    element.preventDefault();
    sendContact();
  });
```

Associated PHP

```
<?php

    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if (
        isset($_POST['name']) &&
        isset($_POST['email']) &&
        isset($_POST['phone']) &&
        isset($_POST['date']) &&
        isset($_POST['Tilaustyyppi']) &&
        isset($_POST['message'])
      ) {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
        $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
        $date = trim($_POST["date"]);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $tilaustyyppi = trim($_POST["Tilaustyyppi"]);
        $autotyyppi = trim($_POST["Autotyyppi"]);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        // Set the recipient email address.
        $recipient = "tipuri.tuning@gmail.com";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "Uusi tilaus $name";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Nimi: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Puhelin: $phone\n";
        $email_content .= "Sposti: $email\n";
        $email_content .= "Päivämäärä: $date\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Tilaustyyppi: $tilaustyyppi\n";

        if(!empty($autotyyppi)) {
            $email_content .= "Autotyyppi: $autotyyppi\n\n";
        }

        $email_content .= "Viesti:\n$message\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "Toimittanut: $name <$email>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Kiitos tilauksestasi! Nähdään pian";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Hupsis! Virhe tapahtui eikä viestiä voitu lähettää, yritä uudelleen.";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "Lähettämisessä tuli ongelmaa, yritä uudelleen!";
    }

?>
```

Associated HTML

```
<form
              action="mail.php"
              method="post"
              id="form"
              class="contact-form ajax-contact"
              style="
                padding: 4rem 4rem 5rem 4rem;
                box-shadow: 0px 13px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
                margin-block: 0rem 10rem;
              "
            >
              <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    class="form-control"
                    name="name"
                    id="name"
                    placeholder="Nimi"
                    required=""
                  />
                  <i class="fal fa-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <input
                    type="tel"
                    class="form-control"
                    name="phone"
                    id="phone"
                    placeholder="Puhelinnumero"
                    required=""
                  />
                  <i class="fal fa-phone"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <input
                    type="date"
                    class="form-control"
                    name="date"
                    id="date"
                    placeholder="Päivämäärä"
                    required=""
                  />
                  <i class="fal fa-calendar-check"></i>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    class="form-control"
                    name="email"
                    id="email"
                    placeholder="Sähköposti"
                    required=""
                  />
                  <i class="fal fa-envelope"></i>
                </div>

                <h6 class="mb-15">Tilaustyyppi<span>(Vaaditaan)</span></h6>
                <div class="form-group form-group-flex col-12">
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="Tilaustyyppi"
                    id="Niin pian kuin mahdollista"
                    value="Niin pian kuin mahdollista"
                    required=""
                    aria-required="true"
                  />
                  <label for="Niin pian kuin mahdollista">
                    Niin pian kuin mahdollista</label
                  >

                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="Tilaustyyppi"
                    id="Ennakkotilaus"
                    value="Ennakkotilaus"
                    required=""
                    aria-required="true"
                  />
                  <label for="Ennakkotilaus">Ennakkotilaus</label>
                </div>

                <h6 class="mb-15">Autotyyppi</h6>
                <div class="form-group form-group-flex col-12">
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="Autotyyppi"
                    id="Henkilöauto"
                    value="Henkilöauto"
                  />
                  <label for="Henkilöauto"> Henkilöauto</label>

                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="Autotyyppi"
                    id="Tilataksi-6"
                    value="Tilataksi 6:lle"
                  />
                  <label for="Tilataksi-6"> Tilataksi 6:lle</label>

                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="Autotyyppi"
                    id="Tilataksi-8"
                    value="Tilataksi 8:lle"
                  />
                  <label for="Tilataksi-8"> Tilataksi 8:lle</label>
                </div>

                <label>
                  Tilauksen tiedot (Nouto- ja kohdeosoite, matkatavarat,
                  lemmikki tai muuta huomioitavaa)
                </label>
                <div class="form-group col-12">
                  <textarea
                    name="message"
                    id="message"
                    cols="30"
                    rows="3"
                    class="form-control"
                    placeholder="Viestisi"
                    required=""
                  ></textarea>
                  <i class="fal fa-comment"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="form-btn col-12 mt-10 text-center">
                  <button type="submit" class="as-btn">Varaa kyyti</button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p class="form-messages mb-0 mt-3"></p>
            </form>
```

Comment: no i didnt, see:
$(form).on('submit', function (element) {
    element.preventDefault();
    sendContact();
  });

Comment: Is the "Associated PHP" the full `mail.php` file?

Comment: This is a lot of code that you are asking us to parse. My suggestion is to remove everything that is unrelated to the problem. Ideally you should have a form with a single field and no JS “validation”. Also, if the page is “refreshing”, that’s HTTP and not PHP